# Reset badge count on Android using React Native Expo

Tags: python, react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm using react native with expo. When a user goes to their notifications I want the badge count to update. The following code in my backend does that (python):

```
from exponent_server_sdk import PushClient, PushMessage
def reset_badge_count(token, new_total):
    response = PushClient().publish(PushMessage(to=token, body=None, data=None, badge=new_total))
    if response:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

It works totally fine on iOS. On Android however, it sends a blank push notification. I don't want any push notification sent I just want to reset the badge count. Does anyone know a workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a push notification to update a badge count? If you are using expo-notifications, then your project is already configured to use firebase. Why not store the badge count in firebase and then when the user interacts with the notification, update the firebase value?

Comment: @PhantomSpooks I have the badge count value in mongoDB. How would I trigger the badge count to change without using push notifications?

Comment: I think you have to set up a listener

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/receiving-notifications/